# Dependency between Talend parameters and server parameters

Tags: exception, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory, talend

I have a Talend job with these JVM parameters:

```
-Xms256M 
-Xmx1500M
```

It worked fine for more than one year, then I got the error below since last Friday:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Any suggestion to repair that?

I want to know if there is something to do on the server side or if everything is to be defined in the job.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you're running your Job; however, these are passed as parameters to the JVM, so you need to pass a larger value for -Xmx and/or review your Job to see if you can use less. It sounds like you've had a data increase over time, that has caused it to tip over.